# Why are there black frames in my project?

Tags: rendering

again, as a prologue, I have close to no experience with Blender. Just getting into it driven by the fact that my Son wants to be a Minecraft Youtuber, and thus needs an Intro. So I found a free Blender template and just started jiggling.

Here's the current state. It's actually being synched to this place whenever I save locally.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9par3l2T-UJQ1paY0tZRXlpN0E

From frame 42 to 52, the rendered output just shows a black screen. This is because the original music had a break there, but the music I will use doesn't. I'm unable to find where this is defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to delete all things from the scene, then add new cube, camera and lamp. Even this doesn't help, hmm... curious setup.

But you can try create new scene via *Link object and data*.

**1. Switch top tab to** *Info*

[image]

**2. Hit** *Plus* **to add new scene and choose** *Link Object Data*

[image]

**3. Go to** *Compositor* **and make sure you are working in a new scene**

[image]

**4. Now your image should render fine.** (I switched plugs for *Alpha Over* node to show final render)

[image]